# Testcafe - How to run code after all the fixtures are run

Tags: sql-server, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I want to create a snapshot of the SQL server DB and then restore it after "all the fixtures" are run.

I can do it after every fixture through .after hook in a fixture. However, that is causing issues while running tests since the DB may be still in transition after a restore. So I would prefer to do it after all the fixtures.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a workaround for now. The workaround is:

1. Add dependency for ts-node. I also had to add tsconfig.json with compiler options' lib property set to es2015 and dom. If not, it was complaining about Promise.
2. I created a file called create-snapshot and created the snapshot there.
3. I created another file called restore-snapshot and restored the snapshot in that file.
4. I added two entries in package.json's scripts like `"create-ss": "ts-node ./create-snapshot.ts"`, `"restore-ss": "ts-node ./restore-snapshot.ts"`
5. Now from Powershell, I run the tests with the command: `npm run create-ss;npm run test-chrome-hl;npm run restore-ss`. This runs the commands sequentially in Powershell. In other terminals you may need to use && or something else instead of ;.

I can avoid "npm run create-ss" by using the .before hook of the fixture by keeping track of a variable to ensure it runs only once. However I cannot do a similar approach when the last test gets executed.

Its a bit of a pain to remember the three commands but I dont see another way so far.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the TestCafe [Programming Interface](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/programming-interface/) API. The TestCafe [Runner class](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/programming-interface/runner.html) returns a Promise object. You can use this object to run your custom cleanup code after all tests/fixtures are completed.

Here's an example:

```
const createTestCafe = require('testcafe');
let testcafe         = null;

createTestCafe('localhost', 1337, 1338)
    .then(tc => {
        testcafe     = tc;
        const runner = testcafe.createRunner();

        return runner
            .src(['tests/fixture1.js', 'tests/fixture2.js', 'tests/fixture3.js'])
            .browsers(['chrome', 'safari'])
            .run();
    })
    .then(failedCount => {
        // Clean up your database here...
        testcafe.close();
    });
```

Comment: Thanks! I did read about it from the documentation. There were a few things I was not sure are: How do I change the browsers at run time. Do I pass them as arguments and use that there? Does the src takes a wild card saying? For e.g, can I say any fixture under src folder (any folders deep) and not update the src every time I add a new fixture.

Comment: You are welcome. Check out the ['src'](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/programming-interface/runner.html#src) argument topic. You can use [glob patterns](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob#glob-primer) to include (or exclude) multiple files. I'm not sure why you need to switch browsers at runtime though. Specify them in the corresponding [browsers](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/programming-interface/runner.html#browsers) argument and execute your tests.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are usually running your tests in order, you could also make a fixture, call it `99_cleanup` and do your cleanup there.