# Execute code before and after multiple Testcafe fixtures

Tags: javascript, testing, e2e-testing, fixtures, testcafe

is there a way of executing a function or a block of code before a complete test run (multiple fixtures) in Testcafe? I know about `beforeEach()` on test level and about `before()` on fixture level, but is there also a way of doing this before and after all tests across all the specified files?

So specifically:

1. **BeforeTestrun()** to setup the database and a test account
2. Run multiple fixtures with multiple tests (over multiple files)
3. **AfterTestrun()** to clean up the database afterwards

I already *kinda* found [a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53270589/testcafe-how-to-run-code-after-all-the-fixtures-are-run) by setting up everything with the Testcafe API, and using multiple `then()` functions before and after to do this, but I was wondering if there is a maybe better or cleaner way of doing this? I am sorry if this is a common question, trying to figure out some new things. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no out-of-the-box way to do this at the moment. It's being discussed in the context of the [Implement test task `setup` and `teardown`](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/745) issue on GitHub, but it is not implemented yet.

Comment: Okay thanks for your reply! For now i'll just use the 'solution' in the question.